# Madelung constant for a two dimensional square crystal lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am looking for a reference that epxlains how to compute the Madelung constant for a two dimensional square crystal lattice where each second atom carries an opposite charge.

I looked at Kittel's book and Ashcroft and Mermin and it's not explained there.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: seems like someone has written a master thesis about that, https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Deb_Banerjee2/publication/237047624_Direct_Calculation_Of_Madelung_Constant/links/02e7e51b045f7bb778000000.pdf

Comment: @linuxick it seems there's no explanation in this thesis on how to manually compute this lattice. He just describes a computer code; I am supposed to find how to compute it for $3\times 3$ and $5\times 5$ cells etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it: draw your crystal, pick one atom in the crystal and write down the coulomb energy for that atom by considering all neighbouring atoms (distances, charges and the number). See attached manuscript.

Edit: I have realised that I have made a small mistake in the manuscript (the last $4/\sqrt{5}$ in the parentheses needs to be $8/\sqrt{5}$) but to show the principle I kept it.

[image]

I have attached a better drawing below to see the exact nearest neighbour distances and count the number of neighbours. The term in parentheses (the Madelung Constant) is an infinite series expansion. You should find out which series is that. For example if you calculate Madelung constant is one dimension the expansion is for $$ln(1+x)= x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+...$$
[image]

Comment: terrific, but what comes after the dots, does it converge for a $7\times 7$ cell?

Comment: I have changed the answer a bit, I hope it is more clear now.